# NgMap error "could not find map"

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ng-map

I am fairly new to Angular, and I am trying to use this to integrate google maps: https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps

The problem I am having is when I try to get the maps instance using NgMap.getMap() When I console.log NgMap.getMap I am getting "could not find map". This is how my code looks:

partials/home.html:

```
<h1>practice locater</h1>
<ng-map id="map" center="[40.74, -74.18]"></ng-map>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('RIThym',['ngResource','ngRoute','ngMap']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
}]);

app.controller('HomeCtrl',['$scope','$resource', 'NgMap',
function($scope, $resource, NgMap){
    var Locations = $resource('/api/locations');
    Locations.query(function(locations){
        $scope.locations = locations;
    });

    var map = NgMap.getMap();
    console.log(map);
    NgMap.getMap().then(function(map){
        console.log(map);
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Can't reproduce error. Works fine in [this PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/FbQKm1j7BUWRrWwsMdwi?p=preview).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply I was able to reproduce it here: http://plnkr.co/edit/N93h2rv6jW3yipze2ktX?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `ng-map` directive has an `id` attribute, the `getMap` function must use that `id` value as its first argument.

HTML

```
<h1>practice locater</h1>
<ng-map id="map" center="[40.74, -74.18]"></ng-map>
```

JS

```
//DO this
NgMap.getMap("map").then(function(map){
//NOT this
//NgMap.getMap().then(function(map){
    console.log(map);
});
```

For more information, see [NgMap Provider API Reference](https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/docs/NgMap.html)